# Input pins not working on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

On my Raspberry Pi Pico input pins are not working:

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)

OutputPin = Pin(21, Pin.OUT)
OutputPin.value(1)

InputPin = Pin(20, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

while True:
    if InputPin.value():
        led.value(1)
    else:
        led.value(0)
    sleep(0.1)
```

[image]

If I press the button the LED should light up but nothing happens. I found current goes from pin 21 to pin 20. I guess pin 20 is not working (other pins didn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wiring does not match your code.  You have connected a button between GP15 and GP16, but your code is not doing anything with either of those pins.  Your code is reading GP20 as an input, but you left that pin disconnected.  Refer to the RP2040 pinout diagram on this page:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/raspberry-pi-pico.html

You got confused between the Raspberry Pi Pico pin numbering and the RP2040 GPIO pin numbering.  MicroPython and pretty much every other RP2040 programming environment uses the latter.